# Understanding vector calculus identity in deriving weak form of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

## TL:DR

How does the following vector calculus identity hold and how is it used to derive the weak form of the heat equation?

$$
\nabla \cdot (vp \nabla u) = v\nabla \cdot (p \nabla u) + p(\nabla v) \cdot (\nabla u) \tag{3}
$$

## Context and Attempt

I am working through "Finite Element Methods: A Practical Guide" (Whiteley, 2017) and attempting to derive the weak form of the following PDE:

[image]

where $\Omega = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. I understand that I have to multiply the equation by a test function $v(x, y) \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $H_0^1$ is a subset of the Sobolev space of order 1 such that $v(x, y) = 0$ at all points where Dirichlet boundary conditions are specified. Since

$$
-(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}) = -\nabla \cdot \nabla u = 1
$$

then multiplying by $v(x, y)$ gives

$$
v(-\nabla \cdot \nabla u) = v \tag{1}
$$

The book then states that the above equation is equivalent to

$$
-\nabla \cdot (v \nabla u) + (\nabla v) \cdot (\nabla u) = v \tag{2}
$$

citing the aforementioned vector identity in equation (3). Below I attempt to show how the left handside of equation (1) is the same as the left hand side of equation (2), **however, I fail to do so, so please help**:

\begin{aligned}
v(-\nabla \cdot \nabla u) &\stackrel{?}{=} -\nabla \cdot (v \nabla u) + (\nabla v) \cdot (\nabla u) \\
-(v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}) &\stackrel{?}{=} \left( - \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
           \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
         \end{bmatrix}^\text{T} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{v \partial u}{\partial x} \\
           \frac{v \partial u}{\partial y} 
         \end{bmatrix} \right) + \left(\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
           \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
         \end{bmatrix}^\text{T} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\
           \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} 
         \end{bmatrix}  \right) \\
-(v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}) &\stackrel{?}= (-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}) + (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}) \\
-(v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}) &\stackrel{?}{=} 0
\end{aligned}

Edit: The derivation of the weak form via green's theorem shown in [weak-formulation-poisson-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154803/weak-formulation-poisson-equation) MathSE post is sufficient for my understanding, but it would still be good to know how my question in the current post can be resolved. See [prove-a-particular-case-of-product-rule-for-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793661/prove-a-particular-case-of-product-rule-for-divergence) MathSE post for the derivation of the listed identity.

Comment: There is a mistake in the second line of the expansion. You have to derive the term $v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ as a product of functions $v$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$. The term with derivatives of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is missing and the identity will be ok once you include it.
Is your question effectively why the "vector identity in Appendix B.2" holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector calculus identity is simply the product rule, which written generally is

$$
\nabla \cdot (v\vec{F}) = v(\nabla \cdot \vec{F}) + \nabla v \cdot \vec{F} \tag{1}
$$

where $v$ is a scalar field and $\vec{F}$ is a vector field.

To use this in the derivation of the weak form of heat (Poisson's) equation, one simply says that $\vec{F} = \nabla u$, and substituting into equation (1),

$$
\nabla \cdot (v \nabla u) = \boxed{v(\nabla \cdot \nabla u)} + \nabla v \cdot \nabla u \tag{2}
$$

noting that the boxed part of the equation matches the form of the equation described in the question after multiplying by $v$,

$$
-v(\nabla \cdot \nabla u) = v
$$

Solving equation (2) for $v(\nabla \cdot \nabla u)$, accounting for the negative sign in front of $v$ in the question, and then integrating over the domain $\Omega$ gives

$$
-\int_{\Omega} v(\nabla \cdot \nabla u)\ d\Omega = -\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u)\ d\Omega + \int_{\Omega} \nabla v \nabla u\ d\Omega \tag{3}
$$

and note that the Divergence theorem

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot \vec{A}\ d\Omega = \oint_{\partial \Omega = \Gamma} \vec{A} \cdot \vec{n}\ d\Gamma
$$

can be applied to

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u)\ d\Omega = \oint_{\partial \Omega = \Gamma} v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}\ d\Gamma \tag{4}
$$

by assigning $\vec{A} = v \nabla u$.

Substituting equation (4) into equation (3) gives the below equation.

$$
-\int_{\Omega} v(\nabla \cdot \nabla u)\ d\Omega = - \oint_{\partial \Omega = \Gamma} v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}\ d\Gamma + \int_{\Omega} \nabla v \nabla u\ d\Omega
$$

Finally, since $v(x, y) \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and thus $v(x, y) = 0$ at all points where Dirichlet boundary conditions are specified, and the boundary domain is defined by $\partial \Omega$, then

$$
\oint_{\partial \Omega = \Gamma} v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}\ d\Gamma = 0
$$

and the weak form of the heat equation specified in the question is

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \nabla u\ d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} v\ d\Omega
$$